# Generator function yield the largest iterable value

Tags: python, generator

I'm a beginner for python, and I'm currently preparing a test for my class. There is one part I'm confused about on one question.

We are asked to create a generator function that only yields the result that is from the largest iterable arguments after all other iterable arguments stop their iteration.

So, my function currently looks like this:

```
def generator(*args):
    args = [iter(a) for a in args]
    while True:
        yielded = False
        for a in args:
            try:
                yield next(a)
                yielded = True
            except StopIteration:
                pass
        if not yielded:
            return
a = generator('abc', 'abcdef', [1,2])
print([i for i in a])

>>> ['a', 'a', 1, 'b', 'b', 2, 'c', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

But what I want is since the argument `'abcdef'`, it will not stop iteration when all other parameters stop iteration right? I want to only print `['d','e','f']`

So, the desired structure for this should be:

```
def generator(*args):
    blah blah

a = generator('abc', 'abcdef', [1,2])
print([i for i in a])

>>>['d','e','f']
```

Is there anything wrong with my function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The task will be easier if you define some helper functions

```
vals = ['abc', 'abcdef', [1, 2]]


def next_or_none(iterator):
    """Return the next item in the iterator, or None if the iterator is done.
    """
    try:
        return next(iterator)
    except StopIteration:
        return None


def myzip(*args):
    """Yield one element from each arg, yield None for arg that are done.
    """
    args = [iter(a) for a in args]
    while True:
        res = [next_or_none(a) for a in args]
        if all(v is None for v in res):  # make sure we stop when all iterators are exhausted
            return
        yield res
```

with those defined all you need to do is loop through the myzip generator until it provides only one value per iteration.

```
def remainder(*args):
    for nextarg in myzip(*args):
        notnones = [v for v in nextarg if v is not None]
        if len(notnones) == 1:
            # wait for all but one iterator to be done before yielding.
            yield notnones[0]

print(list(remainder(*vals)))
```

Comment: Note, this will not work for all lists containing `None` (to fix this problem you could make myzip only return non-None values).

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS:

In this code, iteration is performed only on the largest argument, and only from the position where it is larger.

```
def generator(*args):                                     
    sorts = sorted(args, key=len, reverse=True)           
    choose = sorts[0][len(sorts[0])-len(sorts[1]):]       
    gen = iter(choose)                                    
    while True:                                           
        yielded = False                                   
        try:                                              
            yield next(gen)                               
            yielded = True                                
        except StopIteration:                             
            pass                                          
        if not yielded:                                   
            return                                        
a = generator('abc', 'abcdef', [1,2])                     
print([i for i in a])
```

Comment: You could simplify the last part to `for item in choose: yield item`

Comment: ps: you should explain the strategy you're using with words as well as code (as code-only answers are frowned upon...)